# Bochs and Bios Canonica VirtIO SCSI Disk Device running Windows 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtualization

I have a Windows 2008 R2 server I can only remote this server so I need to know what type of virtual environment is hosted on,

The Bio Manufacturer shows Bochs and hard disk shows: Canonica VirtIO SCSI Disk Device

Is Bochs a VM? and can host x64 guest?
Many thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just ask the hoster what he uses?

Comment: We are received error logs from our application, and we don't know the hoster (Anonymous user) and no way to contact the hoster, we can assist through our net meeting, but no way to contact them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are both telltale signs of a KVM virtual machine. It is almost certainly running on an Ubuntu host, based on the presence of the "Canonical" brand.

Comment: Many thanks Michael, I will try to reproduce and check it.